# how to customise the FCK editor toolbar within Oracle's UCM

Tags: oracle, fckeditor, oracle-ucm

I'm trying to work out how to customise the FCK editor toolbar for contribution for Oracle's Content Server.

I am familiar with how to customise the FCK editor but am unsure of the correct way to apply custom scripts to the standard WYSIWYG editor for contributors.

I have this reference: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14571_01/doc.1111/e10613/c11_scripts.htm#BEIEDBEF

But it does not reveal how to implement the custom configuration scripts and the references send you in loops.

Has anyone done this, know how to do this or has any links to useful sites for this topic?

Thanks

Comment: Universal Content Management using Content Server, SiteStudio and Orcale Database 10g... hope that's what you were after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy enough.
Head to the following folder in your UCM install.
`/weblayout/webform/fckeditor`
Here you will find the FCK source, and some handy doco files.

In Site Studio; check: Site Assets -> Custom Configuration Scripts
This is where you will find the content based files that will expand the FCK editor. 
I believe some samples are installed with the SS component, try your luck with the 'Add to Site' feature.
If they don't show up for your site, search for the 'Web Site Object Type' =  'Custom Configuration Script' or ID = `SS_FCK_` and add them.

Once all this is done, you will have to assign the configuration Scripts to your 'Element Definition'. Under the "Custom Configuration" field (you can add multiple scripts).

The scripts are just JS, you can edit them easily enough within Site Studio.

Comment: 2 years later and I finally tested it out - working first time. Thanks a ton